Turtle-based Python game behaves unexpectedly when it is replayed for the second time
I have created a game using Python's turtle package where you use the Up arrow key to help the turtle cross the screen and avoid obstacles while doing so. It has a Replay button that you can click after you lose in order to reset the game and play again. However, if you lose twice and click the 'Replay' button, the obstacles suddenly start moving faster on the screen and once you lose, the obstacles keep getting generated and appearing over the Game Over message. This does not happen the first two times the game is played.
I believe this is due to some tkinter functionality that I am not aware of. I tried using a debugger to resolve this a few weeks ago and noticed the following in the begin_game function when the turtle hits an obstacle and the game ends:

play_game is set to False because the if cosmo.distance(c) <= 20 evaluates to True

The if cosmo.reach_finish_line condition evaluates to False and this is skipped over

When the if play_game condition is reached, the debugger gets into some tkinter code and at the end of it, goes to the start of the begin_game function and starts executing it. This should not be happening because play_game is set to False, so begin_game should not be recursively called. I even double-checked the value of play_game before this if statement is evaluated, and it was still False.


Does anyone know why this might be happening? Why do the obstacles suddenly move faster when the game is replayed for the second time? And why do they continue to appear on the screen even when the player loses?
Below is the problematic begin_game function.
# Begin game when player hits 'Play' or 'Replay' buttons
def begin_game():
    cosmo.showturtle()
    level_display.show_level()
    play_game = True
    screen.update()

    # Call obstacle_generator methods to create obstacles and move them forward
    obstacle_generator.create_obstacles()
    obstacle_generator.obstacle_move()

    # Detect collision between obstacle and turtle
    for c in obstacle_generator.all_obstacles:
        if cosmo.distance(c) <= 20:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            screen.tracer(0)

            # Iterate over obstacle list, hide turtle, and append to recycle list since this game round is over,
            # and they should not be visible on the end game screen
            for num in range(len(obstacle_generator.all_obstacles)):
                obstacle_generator.all_obstacles[num].hideturtle()
                obstacle_generator.recycle.append(obstacle_generator.all_obstacles[num])
            obstacle_generator.all_obstacles = []

            cosmo.hideturtle()

            # Call function to display end game screen
            end_game()

            play_game = False
            break

    # Detect if player has completed current level
    if cosmo.reach_finish_line():
        level_display.refresh_level()
        obstacle_generator.level_up()

    # Recursively call begin_game function if game is still on
    if play_game:
        screen.ontimer(fun=begin_game, t=100)

